# A DECLARE after an IF in TSQL - when does SQL Server allocate resources?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If I do the following:

```
IF @THING = TRUE BEGIN
     DECLARE @BIGTHING AS BIGINT
END
```

Will SQL Server allocate the resources for the `@BIGTHING`?

Or maybe better asked: does SQL Server parse the stored procedure and allocate all the declared variables before execution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It must as this

```
IF 1=2 BEGIN
     DECLARE @BIGTHING AS BIGINT=0
END

select @BIGTHING
```

runs without problem for me with Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2. Interestingly though, if the variable is defaulted to a value as shown above, it only sets the value if the IF condition is true.

Comment: Same behaviour verified in SQL Server 2014.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that the "unreachable" declaration must still be before the first usage or you get an error.

Answer (score 2):

A variable is available for use in a T-SQL batch from the point at which it's declaration is *parsed* until the end of the batch. This means that a) variable declarations don't take part in any form of control flow, and b) variable names must be unique within a batch, even if they appear to be in mutually exclusive parts of the batch. [SpectralGhost's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27137587/15498) shows the consequence of this.

Answer (score 0):

Allocation isn't exactly the right word for it. All local variables are just given slots on stack as part of the function declaration. Some time is spent zeroing out the values, but that's probably done in mass for the whole stack frame.

In interesting thing is when the code is recompiled. This can happen in the middle of stored procedure for a number of reasons. The one I was told specifically to look out for is altering a temp table. If you make any changes to the temp table, a new execution plan is generated for the rest of the stored proc.